# Using LINQ with MySQL database that can change in production

Tags: mysql, database, linq

I'm writing database code for an MVC3 app that uses MySQL and must support dynamic views.

After development is complete, the app must show new columns that were added to the database correctly. Because of this dynamic requirement, I don't think that I can use Entity Framework.

I've got something going using regular string queries, but I'm wondering if there's a way to set up my project so that I can use LINQ (or EF...) instead to speed up development and make debugging easier. I would also like to create dynamic queries [like this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) because I think working with them would be cleaner than doing a lot of string manipulation.

Is there a way that I can do this? It seems like I can use DbLinq for this, but I haven't found enough documentation to prove that it's stable enough to use in production.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine you are showing results in some sort of data grid. If that is the case, you could just assign DataSet or DataTable to a grid as a datasource, something like that (SQL Server here instead of MySql):

```
var table = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM MyView", connSring);
da.Fill(table);
grid.DataSource = table;
```

I realize, this has nothing to do with LINQ, but since you cannot pre-generate schema, LINQ would be pretty pointless to use here..

Comment: I've got something like what you posted that works. I want to be able to do dynamic LINQ queries instead of just string manipulation, though